# Checking if a string exists using a substring (using linked lists)

Tags: c, string, list, substring, strstr

I need to make a function that receives a substring as an argument and checks if any of the strings in a linked list contain that substring.

The function creates a new linked list with all of the strings that contain the substring given.

The function looks like this:

```
    lista *lista_pesquisa_substring(lista *lst, char *substring)
{
    l_elemento *aux, *curr;
    lista *lis2;
    int i = 0, tamanho;
    lis2 = lista_nova();
    if(lst == NULL || substring == NULL){
            return NULL;
    }
    for (aux = lst->inicio; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo)
            {
                curr = lista_elemento(lis2, i);
                if (strstr(*aux->str, substring) != NULL)
                {
                    lista_insere(lis2, aux->str, curr);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            tamanho = lista_tamanho(lis2);
            printf("Foram carregados %d jogos.\n", tamanho);
            for(i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
            {
                curr = lista_elemento(lis2, i);
                printf("Pos %d -> %s\n", i, curr->str);
            }
            return lis2;
        }
```

The if statement isn't working as intended. It only works if the substring given is exactly the same as a string from the linked list.

For example, if a string from the linked list is "Hello there" and the substring given is "Hello there", the if statement works.
But if the substring is "there", the if doesn't work.

EDIT:
I should also mention that the substring used as an argument is wrote by the user using the fgets function.

I have tried to use a pre-existing string instead to test it and it works. So I'm confused as to why it doesn't work with a string that's input by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I should also mention that the substring used as an argument is wrote by the user using the fgets function.....
>   So I'm confused as to why it doesn't work with a string that's input by the user.

One possible reason that it doesn't work when you take input from user using `fgets()` function is that when user give input and press `ENTER` key, `fgets()` consider the newline character as a valid character and includes it in the input string given by the user. So, if the user gives input string `"there"` and press `Enter` key, the `fgets()` reads the characters from the input stream and stores them in the buffer like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| t | h | e | r | e | \n| \0|
+---------------------------+
                      ^^
```

Remove the trailing newline character from the input buffer before passing it to the function which looks for the substring in the linked list:

```
inbuffer[strcspn(inbuffer, "\n")] = 0; //inbuffer is buffer which holds input string given by user
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it!